# How to Bulk Insert from Named Pipe on remote server using SQL Server 2014?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, named-pipes

This is question is related to answer of [Can Sql Server BULK INSERT read from a named pipe/fifo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197017/can-sql-server-bulk-insert-read-from-a-named-pipe-fifo)

@Grimace_of_Despair provided a solution using C#. See [the GitHub project](https://github.com/GrimaceOfDespair/BulkInsert) for more details.

1. Create a Named Pipe with `server name = .`

   ```
   public NamedPipe(string name, string server, string dataValue)
   {
            _dataValue = dataValue;

            Name = name;
            Server = server;
            Stream = new NamedPipeServerStream(name, PipeDirection.Out, 2,
                                               PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, 
                                               PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
            Stream.BeginWaitForConnection(OnConnection, this);
   }
   ```
2. Bulk Insert using Named Pipe

   ```
   var insertCommand = DbConnection.CreateCommand();

   insertCommand.CommandText = "BULK INSERT [MyTable] FROM '\\.\pipe\mypipe' WITH (FORMATFILE='c:\path\to\formatfile')";
   insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   ```

Above bulk insert command works fine when I am bulk inserting on the same server and using `\\\\.\pipe\mypipe`

When I replace `\\\\.\pipe\mypipe` with `\\\\LocalMachineName\pipe\mypipe`, I get an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.

Does anyone know the reason for this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you inspect the contents of the named pipe in the receiver code?

Comment: Named pipe contains delimited data which i am trying to bulk insert into sql table.
Bulk insert runs successfully when I refer pipe as **\\\\.\pipe\mypipe**. It throws an error when I use **\\\\LocalMachineName\pipe\mypipe**.

Comment: I know. Can you inspect the contents if the pipe, i.e. get the length of the data? Save the data as a text file? Then you can inspect  the data _before_ you try to BULK INSERT it.

Comment: I stored data in a file instead of named pipe. I was able to bulk insert from this file. Is there any permission issue with named pipe which is not allowing me to access it as **\\\\LocalMachineName\pipe\mypipe**

Comment: Did you load this file from the named pipe first? I'm just suggesting: you need to see the data in the named pipe to help you understand the error. Break the issue into smaller pieces. Also perhaps try synchronous instead of asynchronous.

Comment: As stated earlier, contents of named pipe are correct as I am able bulk insert when I refer it as **\\.\pipe\mypipe**